# Summing up Haskell output lines

Tags: haskell

I want to write a programm which would print out only one integer after applying some functions to the lines in text file, so far I have :

```
main = do
   c <- getLine
   let plot = plots (split ',' (change c))
   print plot
   main
```

where plots, split and change are the functions that convert input from string to int removing non-integer chars and then applying some calculations, the problem is that my input file has a lot of lines and I only managed to write a program which applies those functions to every line separately and prints out the result of every line,(I get as much output lines as there are input lines), but I want that this programm would sum up the results of every line and would print out only that number, where should I start or maybe somebody knows the solution? I am new in Haskell so please don't judge :/

Comment: Please add type signatures and a clear specification of what you mean by “sum up the results”.

Comment: *I only managed to write a program [...]* Edit your question and add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your conversion functions work for multi-line inputs, you can probably get away with simply replacing `getLine` with `getContents` and removing the recursive call to `main`. Although if you actually want to read a file, using `readFile` is probably cleaner than using `getContents`, since the latter is typically used for reading from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon what Paul wrote, `getContents` is like `getLine`, but it gives you the entire file in a single string. You can then get a list of lines using `lines`. For example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  print (lines contents)
```

When given the file

```
Haskell
is
neat!
```

will print `["Haskell","is","neat!"]`. From here, you can `map` your line-handling function over that list to get a list of integers, and finally `print (sum resultList)`.